# WPF Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality consumes 10x more memory than HighQuality

Tags: c#, wpf, image, memory, render

I have an image which is about 5k x 5k pixels. 
The image contains a LayoutTransform with a ScaleTransform.

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding ImageSource, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{Binding ImageWidth, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ImageHeight, Mode=OneWay}" Visibility="{Binding ImageVisibility, Mode=OneWay}" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
     <Image.LayoutTransform>
          <ScaleTransform  ScaleX="{Binding ScaleValue, Mode=OneWay}" ScaleY="{Binding ScaleValue, Mode=OneWay}"/>
     </Image.LayoutTransform>
</Image>
```

Since scaling the image is very slow due to the HighQuality option, I decided to set it to LowQuality during the scaling process. As it turns out the LowQuality option consumes much more memory than HighQuality as you can see in the screenshot.

```
RenderOptions.SetBitmapScalingMode(image, BitmapScalingMode.LowQuality); //Reduce quality during resize to improve performance (or not :()
```

The memory peak after setting it to Low is not temporary - it stays until the application is closed. A second or third resize operation has no effect on the peak. 
I believe the Image Control caches the image of some sort - not sure though. 
I am also familliar with a memory leak which can happen if a BitmapImage is not manually destroyed but I think this is not the problem here since the peak happens during the RenderOption-change.

Any ideas are very much appreciated

**EDIT**
This is the code I use to load my image:

```
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(_filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

BitmapSource bmSrc = decoder.Frames[0];
bmSrc.Freeze();

ImageSource = bmSrc;
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you don't explicitly set the rendering mode? The reason I ask is that 'Linear' and 'LowQuality' (which are the same thing) are the default scaling mode.

Comment: Ah, apologies - just realised what you're doing: switching the scaling mode on the *same* image. I'm not sure what behaviour that would have - I've solved similar problems by using an aligned low-quality AND high-quality image, and switching visibility between them on scaling, etc.

Comment: Haha :D I did that too (not in this example, but that is why I still have a Binding to Visibility in the code above) :) But LowQuality consumes much more memory than High. it doesn't matter if I use two seperate images or not.

Comment: @olitee I just removed any RenderOptions in xaml as well as in C#. I can confirm that the peak is caused by the default BitmapScaling Mode. As soon as the Quality is low the memory goes up.

Comment: So what you're saying is that an image set to 'LowQuality' scaling (that does not have it's scaling mode changed), still consumes considerably more memory than the same image in 'HighQuality' mode? That's interesting ... particularly with it being the default scaling mode. I'll do some digging and get back to you ...

Comment: @olitee That is indeed what I am saying. Could not find anything on msdn yet. They actually recommend the approach of switching Modes. thank you very much.

Comment: Just done some testing using a 2k, 4k and 5k image. I find a consistent doubling of the memory footprint when using LowQuality or NearestNeighbour over HighQuality ... however I find that memory is released and collected by the GC within a few seconds. After collection, all scaling types consume the same amount of memory. What version of .NET are you using? I've tested under 4.5, using a 32-bit PNG file as a source.

Comment: @olitee My img is 5k 1 bit per bixel tiff. And my app is .Net 4.0 CP. It does not free memory over duration of 5 minutes. I also updated to .Net 4.5 and it does not free memory over the duration of 5 minutes as well. I guess there is not fix for this issue. If you don't have an idea about why my memory isn't freed over time - you might want to add a short summary of our new knowledge as an answer that I can accept. :)

Comment: That's ok. Confirming your problem isn't really answering your question :) ... Let's leave this open in case anyone has an answer for you. I'll test a 1bit TIFF today under 4.0 CP today just to see if I get the same results.

Comment: @olitee I added code which shows how I load my Image. Maybe you need to use that to reproduce the issue. Thank you for your help! EDIT: As you can see from my screenshot: The first time i set it to low quality the memory is freed after about 1 second. The second, third... time i set it to low the memory isn't freed anymore. Another point I do not understand.

Comment: Hmm. Switched to 4.0 CP with a 1bit 5k TIFF, using your loading code ... same results I'm afraid. I don't seem to be able to reproduce this. When initially switching from High to Low quality, I see a ~5x increase in memory usage, as you describe, but that quickly gets cleaned up by the GC, and subsequent switching does not affect memory usage at all.  Just a thought, but probably unrelated - do you want to make sure you call .Dispose() on that FileStream in your load method? The fact I can't reproduce it may at least rule out the obvious causes. Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Comment: @olitee I could fix the issue today by using two images and adding/removing them to/from the tree. I do believe the peak was caused by changing the BitmapScalingMode inside a Timer.Tick event (different thread?) I did this to create a time buffer to make sure the user has finished zooming. You can add this as an answer since you suggested this approach and it works. You may also write down what I believe caused the issue. Cheers' buddy :)